# how to pass an additional parameter to an OnClick event, asp.net web form?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, sftp

I have a function called "CreateReportForEachCompany" as following:

```
   protected Dictionary<int, List<ReportObject>> CreateReportForEachCompany()
        {
            try
            {
                Dictionary<int, List<ReportObject>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<ReportObject>>();
            
                EnvironmentVariable.setEnvId((int)environmentEnum.mll);      
                
                //bakashot_tarif is a VIEW not a TABLE
                DataTable dt = GeneralDbExecuterService.executeSqlSelectDataScript("select * from bakashot_tarif");                      

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {                   
                    var reportRow = FillObjectWithValues(dr);
                    int company_Id = dr.Field<int>("company_Id");
                    CreateDictionaryPairIfNotExist(dict, company_Id);
                    dict[company_Id].Add(reportRow);
               }
                return dict;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

now lets say I invoked it that way and got myself a dictionary with keys/values as needed.

```
            var dictionary = CreateReportForEachCompany();
```

now.. I have another function named:

`CreateCsvForEachCompany(Dictionary<int, List<ReportObject>> dict)`

that TAKES the dictionary as parameter and creates few csvs based on the dictionary keys..

now those two functions above are executed on button click as following:

```
  protected void ExecuteProgram(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           var dictionary = CreateReportForEachCompany();
           CreateCsvForEachCompany(dictionary);
        }
```

after that, I have a function named TransferSftpOnClick which meant to transfer file via SFTP (secure file transfer protocol ) into a designated location in the server:

```
  void TransferSftpOnClick(Dictionary<int, List<ReportObject>> dict)
        {
            EnvironmentVariable.SetSubject(EnvironmentVariable.appSubjectEnum.btl);
            string systemId = "MLL";
            string fileType = "HIYUV-CHEVRA";
            string chargeMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMM");
            var fileCreationDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            string fileCreationTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss");
            string subject = EnvironmentVariable.appSubjectEnum.btl.ToString().ToUpper();
            string location = EnvironmentVariable.getLocalFilePath() + @"\";

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<ReportObject>> entry in dict)
            {
                FtpUtil ftp = new FtpUtil();
                int key = entry.Key;
                string fileName = systemId + "-" + fileType + "-" + String.Format("{0:00000}", key) + "-" + chargeMonth + "-" + fileCreationDate + "-" + fileCreationTime + ".CSV";
             **ftp.saveFileToFtp(location, key.ToString(), fileName, subject);**
            }
        }
```

I want my function to recognize the dictionary that is executed in function "ExecuteProgram()"
And I want to trigger onClick on TransferSftpOnClick that will just transfer me the files to the designated location.

how can I achieve that? is it even worth doing?
or should I just do this:

```
  FtpUtil ftp = new FtpUtil();
  ftp.saveFileToFtp(location, key.ToString(), fileName, subject);
```

under the CreateCsvPerCompany to avoid that mess?

hope I was clear, thanks

Comment: you can have a class member, you can use that in method `TransferSftpOnClick`

Comment: do you mean like public dictionary<int, list<reportObject> dict {get;set;}?,
is it worth doing that? in terms of right programming? or is it a waste and I should just keep the savefiletoftp under my main function?

Comment: What do you mean by right programming and waste?